# Can I use the output of a model's layer as a target to train that same model?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, layer

Let's say I have a model with one input and two outputs. And I want the output of the third layer of my model to be the y_true in my cost function for my second output.
I've tried this:

```
model.fit(x, [y, model.layers[3].output], ...)
```

But got the error:

```
'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Which I believe is referring to the second y_true I gave the fit method.

Is it possible to do something like this in Keras? If so, how?

Comment: `model.layers[3].output` is a Tensor, not a `numpy.array`, which has indeed no `ndim` attribute. What are you trying to do? Normally you feed fit with `numpy.array`'s.

Comment: It's complex to explain the whole picture but the main thing is I want to train my model using one of its layers' output as a y_true to a cost function.
I realize the output is indeed a tensor with no ndim. Nevertheless I want to compare it with another tensor from the same shape (my output2)

Comment: Maybe you could subtract the first and second output from each other and fit that to a [0,0,...,0] as a `numpy.array`? Although you need to think about what gradient descent and the cost function do in this case.

Comment: Why would it be hard for the network to keep those two outputs exactly the same anyway? Isn't it learning the identity function between output_1 and output_2?

Comment: No, the model I have is a complex junction of other several models, I just tried to simplify it for the question. You are correct, I cannot feed a tensor to fit, but I can use it in a custom loss function like I did in the posted answer

Comment: Honestly, either I am not smart enough to understand or this question-answer is more likely a reference for yourself than informative for others. Are you doing some type of representation learning? I still don't get the logic of fitting one layer to another, like your answer is doing.

Comment: It's not that you're not smart enough, I just didn't give the full information for simplicity, but since you are curious:

I'm trying to do something similar to this: 

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.08637.pdf

If you look at Fig.2, in training, the classifier is fitted to the output of the encoder part of the autoencoder. That's why I needed to fit to a intermediate layer output. Maybe I'm the one doing something unnecessary/wrong? If you think so I'll be listening :)

Comment: Also I'm not sure what "representation learning" is, or if it is the correct term for this application but it sounds like a nice fit for what this network is supposed to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to this by changing only the cost function, like:

```
def custom_euclidean_distance_loss(layer_output):
    from keras import backend as K
    def wrap(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - layer_output))
    return wrap
```

And since I do not use any previously known y_true I just fed a dummy one to fit. Note that the printed metrics from Keras won't be correct this way but the model will train with no problem.

If you do know of a better way (like actually feeding the layer output to fit) please let me know